# Having an issue of retrieving data from firebase to the app

Tags: android, getter-setter

In the code below, the issue is that the data cannot be retrieved from the firebase and once I run it, crashes automatically. Here the I want to retrieve the data from the firebase into the XML activity with the image date, time, and description. but when i run the code just without retrieving the data it works without any issues when i add the retrieving data code it crashes.

### My Java Code Drawer Activity.

```
package com.example.user.carapplication;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

    import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


public class OwnerDrawer extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FirebaseAuth OwnerAuth;
    private DatabaseReference OwnerRef, PostsRef;
    private CircleImageView OwnNavProfileImge;
    private TextView OwnNavProfileName;
    String currentUserID;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private RecyclerView postList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_owner_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        OwnerAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        OwnerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Owners");
        currentUserID = OwnerAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        //for the navigation drawer button to open and close
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        postList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.OwnerPostCars);
        postList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        postList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);



        View navView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_owner_drawer);
        OwnNavProfileName = (TextView)navView.findViewById(R.id.NavOwnerUserName);
        OwnNavProfileImge = (CircleImageView)navView.findViewById(R.id.NavOwnerProfileImage);

        OwnerRef.child(currentUserID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists())                {
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("fullname"))
                    {
                        String fullname = dataSnapshot.child("fullname").getValue().toString();
                        OwnNavProfileName.setText(fullname);
                    }
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage"))
                    {
                        String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.with(OwnerDrawer.this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(OwnNavProfileImge);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(OwnerDrawer.this, "Profile name does not exist...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        DisplayAllCarsPost();

    }


    public void DisplayAllCarsPost()
    {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, PostsViewHolder>
                        (
                                Posts.class,
                                R.layout.posted_cars,
                                PostsViewHolder.class,
                                PostsRef
                        )
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(PostsViewHolder viewHolder,  Posts model, int position)
                    {
                        viewHolder.setFullname(model.getFullname());
                        viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
                        viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                        viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                        viewHolder.setProfileimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getProfileimage());
                        viewHolder.setPostimage(getApplicationContext(), model.getPostimage());
                    }
                };
        postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
    public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View mView;

        public PostsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setFullname(String fullname)
        {
            TextView username = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_profile_username);
            username.setText(fullname);
        }

        public void setProfileimage(Context ctx, String profileimage)
        {
            CircleImageView image = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.PostCircularImageView);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(profileimage).into(image);
        }

        public void setTime(String time)
        {
            TextView PostTime = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.Post_time);
            PostTime.setText("    " + time);
        }

        public void setDate(String date)
        {
            TextView PostDate = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.Post_date);
            PostDate.setText("    " + date);
        }

        public void setDescription(String description)
        {
            TextView PostDescription = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.car_description);
            PostDescription.setText(description);
        }

        public void setPostimage(Context ctx1, String postimage)
        {
            ImageView PostImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.car_post_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx1).load(postimage).into(PostImage);
        }
    }





    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser =  OwnerAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null)
        {
            SendUserTologinActivity();
        }
        else
        {
            CheckUserExistence();
        }
    }
    // to see if the user validation and his authenticated so if not, the user will be send to the setup activity.
    private void CheckUserExistence()
    {
        final String current_user_id = OwnerAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        OwnerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public      void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id))
                {
                    SendUserToSetupActivity();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void SendUserToSetupActivity()
    {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(OwnerDrawer.this, OwnerSetup.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserToSettingsActivity()
    {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(OwnerDrawer.this, OwnerSettings.class);
        settingsIntent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(settingsIntent );
        finish();
    }


    private void SendUserTologinActivity() {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(OwnerDrawer.this,OwnerLogin.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserToOwnerPost() {
        Intent PostIntent = new Intent(OwnerDrawer.this,OwnerPost.class);
        PostIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(PostIntent);
        finish();
    }
    private void SendUserToOwnerHome() {
        Intent HomeIntent = new Intent(OwnerDrawer.this,OwnerDrawer.class);
        HomeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(HomeIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_Home) {
            SendUserToOwnerHome();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Profile) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Posting_Cars) {
            SendUserToOwnerPost();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Chat) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Chat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Edit_profile) {
            SendUserToSettingsActivity();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Edit Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if (id == R.id.nav_Logout) {
            OwnerAuth.signOut();
            SendUserTologinActivity();
            Toast.makeText(OwnerDrawer.this, "Logged Out Successfull...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}




**The Post Class where the getters and setters methods**

package com.example.user.carapplication;





public class Posts
{
    public String uid, time, date, postimage, description, profileimage, fullname;



    public Posts(String uid, String time, String date, String postimage, String description, String profileimage, String fullname) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.time = time;
        this.date = date;
        this.postimage = postimage;
        this.description = description;
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getPostimage() {
        return postimage;
    }

    public void setPostimage(String postimage) {
        this.postimage = postimage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getProfileimage() {
        return profileimage;
    }

    public void setProfileimage(String profileimage) {
        this.profileimage = profileimage;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }
}
```

### My XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/post_profile_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/PostCircularImageView"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/post_profile_username"
                android:layout_width="214dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="user name"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Post_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Has Posted A new Car"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Post_date"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Post_time"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/car_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:text="Car Description"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/car_post_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
My Logcat
---------
08-19 17:36:56.265 9271-9271/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
08-19 17:36:56.269 9271-9271/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SM-G955F_8.0.0_0013, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
08-19 17:36:56.271 9271-9271/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.example.user.carapplication 
08-19 17:36:56.350 9271-9271/? I/zygote64: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-19 17:36:56.610 9271-9271/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
08-19 17:36:56.915 9271-9332/? I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from the current namespace instead.
08-19 17:36:56.971 9271-9332/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
08-19 17:36:57.177 9271-9271/? D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
08-19 17:36:57.241 9271-9271/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
08-19 17:36:57.244 9271-9271/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-19 17:36:57.270 9271-9368/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12451
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
08-19 17:36:57.271 9271-9368/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.user.carapplication
08-19 17:36:57.271 9271-9368/? D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
08-19 17:36:58.057 9271-9271/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-19 17:36:58.063 9271-9271/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.user.carapplication, PID: 9271
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.user.carapplication/com.example.user.carapplication.OwnerDrawer}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.user.carapplication.OwnerDrawer.onCreate(OwnerDrawer.java:64)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
08-19 17:36:58.106 9271-9271/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9271 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post your error logs...

Comment: there is no error appears

Comment: Check your logcat for crash logs..

Comment: I have added my logcat to the code above

Comment: Looks like `findViewById(R.id.fab)` is returning `null`, you might need to check that your layout has the right id and type.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `activity_owner_drawer` XML has `FloatingActionButton` with id `fab`?

Seems like below line returns `null`.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
```

Which in-turn throws `NPE` in below line.

```
fab.setOnClickListener()
```

Comment: yeah, it's in the drawer activity which I have created by creating the drawer navigation activity. but I haven't used it cause it's created automatically with the activity

Comment: I have solved the floating action button issue. but it still the same problem

Comment: Still, couldn't solve the issue. anyone can provide a solution will be highly appreciated